# How to read a text file and store into an array without knowing the size?

Tags: c++, arrays, text-files

I am new here.

How to read a text file and store it into an array, without knowing the number of data in the text file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream data;
    int a[100];
    int i=0;

    data.open("test.txt");
    while(data>>a[i]){
        cout << a[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }
    data.close();
}
```

In my code, the array size is fixed. Is there any solution without using `<vector>` library? I can increase the size of the array as large as I can but it doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: You can use containers (e.g. [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector))

Comment: If you don't want to use `std::vector` (which I don't understand, really), you have to do the same manually. Dynamically allocate memory and extend it when more space is needed.

Comment: Use dynamic allocated array - `new` and so on

Comment: Actually this is a very small part of my assignment and <vector> is not allowed to be used, given in the instruction.

Comment: As long as you do not anticipate that the test.txt file will have more than 100 elements, `while(i < 100 && data>>a[i])`

Comment: You can manually manage the memory. But any solution that is not using `std::vector` is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to just use a `std::vector`.

---

If you are not willing to do that then conceptually you have to

1. Count the number of data: `X`
2. Allocate enough memory  to store `X` data items.

Something like the following should do the job (Note: I did not test the code)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

size_t data_size(const string name)
{
    size_t c = 0;
    ifstream data;
    data.open(name);

     while(data>>a[i])
        c++;

    data.close();
    return c;
}

int main(){
    string name = "test.txt"

    int* a = new int [data_size(name)] ;
    int i=0;

    ifstream data;
    data.open("test.txt");
    while(data>>a[i]){
        cout << a[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }
    data.close();
}
```

Comment: To count the elements in the stream you can `std::distance(std::istream_iterator<int>(data), std::istream_iterator<int>{});` Rather than open the file twice simple seek to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::basic_string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(){
ifstream data;
std::string s = "";

data.open("test.txt");
while(data>>s);
data.close();
}
```

Comment: It should work very well, but if OP wants to use `int`, `std::string` is not the way to got.

Comment: Hi @MartinYork, please don't get mad. [see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: Fair. My initial comment was overboard.

Answer (score 0):

You could enlarge your array, when ever it is too small. Use a size, you would think fits the best and only enlarge, when more data is given.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main() {
    std::ifstream data;
    int size = 100;
    int* a = new int[size];
    int i = 0;

    data.open("test.txt");
    if (data.is_open()) // check if file is open
        return -1;

    while (data.peek() != EOF) {
        if (i >= size) {
            int old_size = size;
            size *= 2; // double the size, or what ever. just make it bigger
            int* new_array = new int[size]; // create new array with new size
            std::copy(a, a + old_size, new_array); // copy data to new array
            int* tmp1 = a; // assign old array to a tmp pointer, to not lose the memory
            a = new_array; // assign the newly allocated memory to the pointer
            delete[] a; a = nullptr; // delete the old memory
        }
        data >> a[i];
        std::cout << a[i] << '\n';
        i++;
    }
    data.close();
    // after you don't need the data anymore; delete[]
    delete[] a; a = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

---

One thing I learned the hard way, NEVER use `using namespace std;`. You open an enormously large namespace. If you define, by accident, an function, which has the same name as one in `std`, you will get a compiler error, which is very hard to get, what it is about.

---

Another word of advice, you really should have a look at `std::vector` and all the other STL containers. They will lessen much of the pain.

Comment: Unfortunately `int copy[size];` is not standard C++. Also why would you copy to a temporary and then copy to the destination. Just create the new version copy to there and then release the old version.

Comment: Also note if `i == size` then `while(data>>a[i])` just wrote a value one past the end of your allocated memory and you have overwritten memory that does not belong to you and thus invoked undefined behavior.

Comment: Setting a to null here `delete[] a; a = nullptr;` is actually a bad idea. In situations where you have a double delete the debug invironment will not be able to catch and thus warn you about this type of error in debugging. Simple call `delete` on the variable `a` then let it fall out of scope.

Comment: Prefer `"\n"` over `std::endl` unless you really want to force a flush which is usually not the case.

Comment: @MartinYork well, your first two comments, thanks for that. the other two... I don't get or dissagree with

Comment: Setting a value to `nullptr` actually byes you nothing. So its a waste. There are lots of situations where the debug version of the standard library on several compilers will actually detect the incorrect usage of released pointers so not setting it to null will actually help you find problems rather than solve anything.

Comment: The trouble with `std::endl` is the extra flush. The trouble is that most programmers are actually terrible at understanding when to flush the buffer and basically always do it at the wrong time. If you want to force a flush always use an unbuffered stream (std::cerr !!!). The good thing about streams is that they will automatically flush themselves when it is appropriate to do so forcing a flush is a waste. There is no situation where you **need** to force a flush (exception debugging an error).

Comment: One of the biggest issues we see from beginners is complaints that the C++ streams are not as efficient as the C streams. Of course this is usually caused by incorrect usage of the stream by the beginner and continuously flushing the buffer when not needed. Please have a look at `codereview.stackexchange.com`. This is a common recommendation in all C++ code reviews where `std::endl` is used.

Comment: @MartinYork `nulltpr` - In the meanwhile I tried several gcc (4.8 - 10.0), clang (3.5 - 10) and visual studio compiler (vs 2013 - 2019) versions. Never ever did I get any kind of error or misbehavior. All common flags enabled - nothing. I can't share your concerns on that. Maybe you should share your concerns with Bjarne. Why? He is director of the following website, where `delete ptr; ptr=nullptr;` is indeed recommended. [Why doesn’t delete null out its operand?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-zero) Maybe I totally misread that FAQ, but there it is explicitly recommended.

Comment: @MartinYork You may be right about the flush thing. But is it really a concern there? OP doesn't want to optimize, OP wants to have a working code. If it is about optimization, pleas be my guest. Otherwise, I would suggest, not to overload beginners.

Comment: @skratchi.at: https://onlinegdb.com/SJIV84EnB Run this. Shows the debug environment will warn you about this type of error. This will help you discover errors that otherwise would go undetected and would lead to bigger issues in production later.

Comment: @skratchi.at I would say that you are the one overloading beginners by teaching the incorrect method. The whole point is to teach them the correct method first. Then you can introduce advanced features like flushing once they have understood the basics. Since flushing is done automatically this is something we don't need to introduce to beginners. Bad habits are hard to change for beginners (as this conversation shows with you) so we should not teach bad habbits to start with.

Comment: @MartinYork Next time simply provide some reference, and not try to convince me with some shady arguments. [Stop using std::endl](https://articles.emptycrate.com/2016/04/18/stop_using_std_endl.html) It's not that I don't want to learn new stuff... but not by taking someones word, without reverence and proof!

Comment: @skratchi.at Shady argument! I pointed you at a site full of C++ experts who recommend not to use it. https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: PS. If you want performance rather than just makeing it chug you should check out [sync_with_stdio](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to count the elements in the file. Then allocate the correct amount of memory. Then copy the data into that memory.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream    data("test.txt");

    std::size_t  count = std::distance(std::istream_iterator<int>(data),
                                       std::istream_iterator<int>{});

    data.fseek(0); // Post C++11 this works as expected in older version you
                   // will need to reset the flags as well.

    int data = new int[count];
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(data), std::istream_iterator<int>{},
              data);
}
```